# Select all child elements recursively in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can you select all child elements recursively?

```css
div.dropdown, div.dropdown > * {
    color: red;
}
```

This class only throws a class on the defined className and all immediate children. How can you, in a simple way, pick all childNodes like this:

```css
div.dropdown, 
div.dropdown > *, 
div.dropdown > * > *, 
div.dropdown > * > * > *, 
div.dropdown > * > * > * > * {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 810, accepted):

Use a **white space** to match all descendants of an element:

```css
div.dropdown * {
    color: red;
}
```

`x y` matches every element *y* that is inside *x*, however deeply nested it may be - children, grandchildren and so on.

The asterisk `*` matches any element.

Official Specification: [CSS 2.1: Chapter 5.5: Descendant Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

Comment: it works, but now it overrides all other classes even if they have a higher priority.. (they are placed later in the css file)

Comment: The selector also plays a role in what priority the properties have, not just where in the file they appear. You could try adding ` !important` to your values, e.g. `color: red !important;`

Comment: I know, it's a bit ugly. You could instead try writing more precise selectors, chances are, this would work too. (e.g. `#head ul` → `#head ul#navi`)

Comment: I don't think I get it :) could you please do a better example?

Comment: Okay, very basic example: `p.xy` is more important than `p`, because it is kind of more specific. http://jsfiddle.net/ftJVX/

Comment: what if I want all child that had a specific class?

Comment: How to use hover state for these elements      'div.dropdown *:hover' does not work

Comment: @MEM try this: p .childWithClass. Jithin Jose are all * selector elements the same elements? if so, try div.dropdown element:hover. see http://allcssselectors.com

Comment: I think with a good CSS structure inheritance should do the work in itself.

Answer (score 216):

The rule is as following :

```css
A B {
  /* B is descendant of A */
}
```

```css
A > B {
  /* B is direct child of A */
}
```

So

```
div.dropdown *
```

instead of

```
div.dropdown > *
```

Answer (score 0):

[Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

> The descendant combinator — typically represented by a single space ("
> ") character — combines two selectors such that elements matched by
> the second selector are selected if they have an ancestor (parent,
> parent's parent, parent's parent's parent, etc.) element matching the
> first selector.

```css
details details {
  margin-left:48px;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>A</summary>
  A is a letter in the alphabet.
</details>
<details open>
  <summary>B</summary>
  B is a letter in the alphabet.
  <details open>
    <summary>1</summary>
    1 is a number.
    <details open>
      <summary>*</summary>
      * is a character.
    </details>
  </details>
  <details open>
    <summary>2</summary>
    2 is a number.
  </details>
</details>
```