# How to show all child nodes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="javascript:(void);" id="lnkP">show all children</a>
<a href="javascript:(void);" id="lnkC1">hide child 1</a>
<a href="javascript:(void);" id="lnkC2">hide child 2</a>

<div id="p" style="display:none;">
<div id="c1">child 1</div>
<div id="c2">child 1</div>...
</div>​

$("#lnkP").click(function(){
    $("#p").children().show(); //seems there's a problem here...
});
$("#lnkC1").click(function(){
   $("#c1").hide(); 
});
$("#lnkC2").click(function(){
   $("#c2").hide(); 
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CBGsF/1/

What I am trying to do is:

1. `p` is a parent container
2. click `show all children` link, display
   **all child divs** under `p`
3. click `lnkC1` or `lnkC2` to hide
   individual child div

But it seems that I didn't get `.children()` working correctly. So how to fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: As jQuery selector is basically CSS selectors with some additional custom things, so would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the parent (`#p` in your case) has a `display:none`, it's children won't be visible.

You'll need to show the parent first,

```
$("#p")
.show()
.children().show();
```

(jQuery's chaining, very helpful)

Please try and get rid of the inline styling (it gets unmanageable after a while), use classes as much as possible.

You can have a class in css,

```
.displayNone
{
    display: none;
} 
.displayBlock
{
   display: block;
}
```

And then use jquery methods `.removeClass()`, `.addClass()` or `.toggleClass()` to show/hide your elements.

This is just a recommendation :)

Test link: http://jsfiddle.net/CBGsF/8/

Answer (score 2):

You need to show the `#p` also

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CBGsF/7/

```
$("#lnkP").click(function(){
    $("#p").show().children().show(); //Add show() before children.show call
});
$("#lnkC1").click(function(){
   $("#c1").hide(); 
});
$("#lnkC2").click(function(){
   $("#c2").hide(); 
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CBGsF/5/

```
$("#lnkP").click(function(){
$("#p").show();
$("#p").children().show();
});
  $("#lnkC1").click(function(){
   $("#c1").hide(); 
});
$("#lnkC2").click(function(){
   $("#c2").hide(); 
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent element is set to "display":"None" That is the problem

```
$("#p").css("display","block"); //is required in show all anchor click
```

Check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CBGsF/6/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I thought `.children()` would search for invisible nodes as well. Well, I was wrong on that.