# Bootstrap .nav-tabs border-bottom won't go away

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so I'm using the Bootstrap's nav panels and I have them fixed to the top along with an image bar.  The problem is that I cannot remove the bottom-border from it no matter what I try.  Here is the code as it is:

```
.header-wrapper {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.top {
background-color: #2960f7;
margin: 0;
padding: 5em 0 4em 0;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
}

.top h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs {
border-bottom: none;
position: fixed;
top: 124px;
background-color: #2960f7;
color: #fff;
border-color: #fff;
z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-tabs .active {
    color: #2960f7;
}

.nav-tabs li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2960f7;
}

.nav-tabs li, .nav-tabs li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

And the HTML of the tabs and header:

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
   <div class="top">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>        
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="skillset.html">Skillset</a></li>
        <li><a href="history.html">Work History</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I look at it I see the line in the CSS element in Chrome that shows the `.nav-tabs {border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd}`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghstet23/3/

The long and the short, how can I get that bottom border to go away if setting `.nav-tabs` to `bottom-border: none;` won't work?

Comment: There should be three dependencies with this if it did not go through:
`http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js` `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js` `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Figured it out: I had to add `<style> .nav-tabs { border-bottom: none;}</style>` to the `head`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the following code to the `head`

```
<style>
  .nav-tabs { 
    border-bottom: none;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by bottom border you mean the underline under your nav options you can use `text-decoration: none;` like so in your css:

```
.nav-tabs li, .nav-tabs li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; /* Add this */
}
```

Comment: Got it, I might suggest trying `margin-bottom: 0;` on the `.nav-tabs` class. This is just going off the fiddle, which is obviously a bit different from your actual page, but let me know!

Comment: Well the nav is the same I'm using the colors to detect the bottom border. let me update the fiddle

Comment: Updated the fiddle so that you can see the static bottom border.  This is really all I want is for that white spot under my nav to not be there.

Comment: Does your fiddle look like this also? http://imgur.com/14h9wct I must be missing some dependencies?

Comment: Yea there's three dependencies that you don't have.  Did they not go through when I shared? ->`http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js`  `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js`  `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: I see those in there, it may just be something with my fiddle on my machine :( Is your site deployed anywhere or are you running locally?

Comment: Running it local off of VS

Comment: @gffbss it is the mixed protocols in the dependecies use this one https://jsfiddle.net/ghstet23/7/

Comment: @buddthechud try setting `border-bottom: 0` on the class `.nav-tabs` rather than `none`. Let me know! http://imgur.com/ndu8lJS

Answer (score 0):

On the bootstrap.min.css there is a border set on hover

```
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
    border-color: #eee #eee #ddd;
}
```

On your local stylesheet after you load bootstrap add this to override the bottom border

```
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
}
```

To remove the white border at the bottom

```
.nav-tabs { border-bottom: none; }
```

Check it here

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghstet23/9/)

Comment: @buddthechud That's ``.nav-tabs { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; } ``change that to whatever color you want or make it transparent

Comment: Okay so it apparently works in Fiddle but not in the browser... Going to restart the debug in VS. -> Restarted and it is still showing in all browsers so something in Fiddle is following the rules when nothing else is...

Comment: @buddthechud Where did you put the ``.nav-tabs`` to override the border-bottom ? Is it after the bootstrap is loaded ?

Comment: @buddthechud Whenever you add dependencies on JSFIddle make sure you don't include the http or https to avoid mixed protocols issues

Answer (score 0):

Remember, styles are inherited. Start butchering it from the top-parent down to find your anomalies.

For example, if you have a div inside a div inside a wrapper div, and you apply a border to the wrapper, both inner divs will get borders also.

In that example, if you are like "hey wtf, I only wanted the parent to have a border." Then, you would add "border: none;" to BOTH inner divs.

A person would also be interested in:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

eg:

```
 div > div > * {
   border: none;
 }
```

[Select all child elements recursively in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css)