# Meaninig of Asterisks(*) between css selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My question is about asterisk sign between css selectors. It seems asterisk can ignore selectors by the number of asterisks between two elements.

Example 1 :

```css
ul * li {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Sub-item 3</li>
          <li>
            <ol>
              <li>Sub-item 4</li>
              <li>Sub-item 4</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example 2 :

```css
ul * * * li {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Sub-item 3</li>
          <li>
            <ol>
              <li>Sub-item 4</li>
              <li>Sub-item 4</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example 3 :

```css
ul * * * * * * * li {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>Sub-item 2</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Sub-item 3</li>
          <li>
            <ol>
              <li>Sub-item 4</li>
              <li>Sub-item 4</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please consider my question is about asterisk between two elements and its behavior is different when use as `selector *`.
Can anyone explain how how this happens? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css

Comment: @NisargShah not related to that question. my question is about * between elements not after element and for selecting all elements after that.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is the [universal selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#universal-selector). It matches any element.

It is being applied in conjunction with the [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#descendant-combinators).

So `ul * li` means "a `li` that is a descendant of any element that is a descendant of a `ul`". Or, in other words, "a `li` that is a descendant of a `ul` but not a  child of the `ul` that the `ul` part of the selector matched".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so `ul * li` represents grandchild of ul, `ul * * * li` represents grand grandchild of ul and so on.

Comment: "represents grandchild of ul" — No. It's a descendant combinator, not a child combinator. It could be a grandchild, great-grandchild, etc.