# Aframe select by component

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

Is there a way to select all entities with a particular component attached?

I was trying `document.querySelectorAll(".shadow");` and various other combinations to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors) - which allows grabbing HTML nodes by their attributes. a-frame components are pretty much [custom made HTML attributes](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/component.html#component-html-form) - you're setting them using `setAttribute()` :)

In your case it would be `document.querySelectorAll("[shadow]")`

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ou06mzte/).

Comment: Thanks @Piotr that's the one I was looking for much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/13331155):

> That said, the Selectors Level 4 Working Draft includes a :has()
> pseudo-class that will provide this capability. It will be similar to
> the jQuery implementation.
>
> li:has(> a.active) { /* styles to apply to the li tag */ } **However, as
> of 2020, this is still not supported by any browser.**
>
> **In the meantime, you'll have to resort to JavaScript if you need to
> select a parent element.**

**In short, there is no `querySelectorAll` to do this for you.**

To do this, you need to select all children with class `shadow`, then select all their parents like so:

```js
var children = document.querySelectorAll(".shadow");
var parents = [];

children.forEach(child => {
  parents.push(child.parentElement);
})

console.log(parents);
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

[An article on the limits of CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css)

Comment: I'm not sure if components are registered in the same way as classes because querySelectorAll(".shadow") returns empty - I have just added an empty made up class and was able to select using that - seems a bit hacky though

Comment: Yes, I know. In a real environment you would do something like `querySelectorAll("a-image")` etc. Seems hacky, but there is no way to do this with CSS (`querySelector` is in effect just a CSS selector). See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: I changed the answer above ^