# How to remove any spacing from bootstrap toast message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a `bootstrap` alert message as an overlay toast (so it auto hides, and is shown above other elements).

Problem: I have a spacing at the bottom of the toast, and cannot get rid of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/dertqczw/

```
<div data-delay="30000" id="myToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;">
  <div class="toast-body">
     <div class="alert fade show alert-primary" role="alert">Success</div>
  </div>
</div>

//show toast with:
$("#myToast").toast('show');
 
/* get rid of toast styles */
.toast-body {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.toast {
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the `margin` on the `.alert-primary`

```
.alert-primary {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3tuk6ob/)

---

If you wish to remove the margin for all the alerts, target the `.alert` class;

```
.alert {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ts1kpho/2/)

---

To only target `.alert` inside an `toast`; target all the [child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css);

```
.toast-body .alert {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ts1kpho/1/)

Comment: How could I remove the margin for just any alert type?

Comment: use the `.alert` class if you wish to target ALL alerts

Comment: Great, and if I'd only want to target alerts *inside* just any toasts?

Comment: Please check the edit. However, this should be included in the OP since it's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
#myToast .alert {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Or a more general solution:

```
.alert {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

EDIT:

For only toast alerts:

```
.toast-body .alert {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Compared to the other answer, this one is just slightly better due to the specificity of setting 'margin-bottom', which is what the OP wanted, instead of 'margin'.

Comment: That's nice. Can I restrict the css on alerts only **inside** toasts (independent of a `#myToast` id?