# how to target an element child in css

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone in my case I want to target the 3 element for example, and I have the tags different, the 3 element can be `p` or `div` or something else, so I want to just target the 3 element what ever it is, i want to select always the 3 element.

Can I do that with CSS, if any help?

For example :

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
  <span><span>
  <div></div> //3 element here is div
  <a></a>
</div>
```

Or :

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <span><span>
  <p></p> //3 element here is p
  <a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your examples aren't very helpful, because you don't say what you want to do with them. Do you mean you want to style the _third_ element? If so, look up "nth child".

Comment: Do you mean like this `div > *`? or `div *:nth-child(3)` or?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select all child elements recursively in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css)

Comment: ^^ This one is kinda the reverse of your question, but explains the difference between the way to select all children and all descendants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you would always have 4 tags, and want to target first 3,

```css
div > *:not(:last-child){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
  <span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span>
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <a>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</a>
</div>
```

2. You could also target first 3 elements like below,

```css
div > *:nth-child(-n+3){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
  <span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span>
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <a>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i just want to target always 3 element whatever it is

Comment: div > :nth-child(1), div > :nth-child(2), div > :nth-child(3){
   background: red;
}

Comment: [code 7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13087426/code-7) , I have updated the answer.
You could also check the 2nd way.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to select first three child of a parent div(or any other element), you can do something like this,

```
.parent:nth-child(1),
.parent:nth-child(2),
.parent:nth-child(3){
   //Your styles
}
```

Above code would select 1st, 2nd and 3rd child of the parent div to which i gave a class of parent.
Also, if you want to select all the child of that parent div you could simply do as,

```
.parent > *{
  //Your styles
}
```

this code would select all the child of the .parent div