# CSS: Selector for Google's search box

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, css-specificity, userstyles

I am trying to make Google's homepage more to my liking. I have added the following CSS:

```css
* {
   /* zoom: */
   /* font-size: 103% ; */
    min-width: 0px !important ;
}

input {
    width: 1000px !important ;
}

#top_nav > * {
    /* font-size: 2em !important;; */
    zoom: 200% ;
}

.logo {
    /* display: none; */
}

#top_nav > * > * > * > * > * {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important; 
}
#center_col {
    margin-left: 3em !important;
    width: 90vw ;
}

.g , cite, #res h3 {
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow-wrap: anywhere !important;
    white-space: wrap !important;
    overflow: hidden !important ;
    max-width: none !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    font-size: 1.4em !important;
    word-break: break-word;
}

div {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

[image]

But I can't find a good, maintainable way to select the search box for CSS alterations. I want to add a `zoom: 2` to it, and make its width fill the empty space after it.

BTW, is there any better selector than `#top_nav > * > * > * > * > *` available for the top navigation menu bar? I tried using `!important` but it was overridden by Google's own CSS.

---

Here is the HTML that contains the search box:

```html
<div
  class="CvDJxb big"
  jscontroller="ZyRBae"
  jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md"
  id="searchform"
>
  <div id="_zdijYK-pCI3QUv3GpYAD5">
    <span class="gb" style="display: none"></span>
    <div class="gb_qa gb_0d gb_Wa gb_Ic" id="gb">
      <div class="gb_Xd gb_Ta gb_Jd" data-ogsr-up="">
        <div class="gb_Te">
          <div class="gb_Oc">
            <div
              class="gb_C gb_cd gb_i gb_Bf"
              data-ogsr-fb="true"
              data-ogsr-alt=""
              id="gbwa"
            >
              <div class="gb_Af">
                <a
                  class="gb_D"
                  aria-label="Google apps"
                  href="https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  role="button"
                  tabindex="0"
                  ><svg class="gb_We" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                      d="M6,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM16,6c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2s2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2zM12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2z"
                    ></path></svg
                ></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a
            class="gb_4 gb_5 gb_ae gb_4c"
            href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&amp;passive=true&amp;continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dharry%26rlz%3D1C5CHFA_enIR733IR733%26oq%3Dharry%26aqs%3Dchrome..69i57j69i60j69i65l3j69i60l3.1174j0j1%26sourceid%3Dchrome%26ie%3DUTF-8&amp;ec=GAZAAQ"
            target="_top"
            >Sign in</a
          >
        </div>
        <div
          style="
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 328px;
            z-index: 991;
            height: 0px;
            margin-top: 57px;
            transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
            right: 0px;
            margin-right: 4px;
          "
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sfbg" style="margin-top: -20px"><div class="sfbgg"></div></div>
  <form
    class="tsf"
    action="/search"
    id="tsf"
    data-submitfalse="q"
    method="GET"
    name="f"
    role="search"
  >
    <div jsmodel="vWNDde" jsdata="MuIEvd;_;Ac21RE">
      <div
        jscontroller="W5mjOc"
        jsmodel="QubRsd"
        class="A8SBwf"
        jsdata="LVplcb;_;"
        jsaction="lX6RWd:w3Wsmc;DkpM0b:d3sQLd;IQOavd:dFyQEf;XzZZPe:jI3wzf;Aghsf:AVsnlb;iHd9U:Q7Cnrc;f5hEHe:G0jgYd;vmxUb:j3bJnb;R2c5O:LuRugf;qiCkJd:ANdidc;NOg9L:HLgh3;uGoIkd:epUokb;zLdLw:eaGBS;rcuQ6b:npT2md"
      >
        <div class="logo">
          <a
            href="https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQPAgS"
            title="Go to Google Home"
            id="logo"
            data-hveid="18"
            ><img
              src="/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"
              alt="Google"
              height="30"
              width="92"
              data-atf="1"
          /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="RNNXgb" jsname="RNNXgb">
          <div class="SDkEP">
            <div class="iblpc" jsname="uFMOof">
              <div class="CcAdNb">
                <span class="QCzoEc z1asCe MZy1Rb"
                  ><svg
                    focusable="false"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"
                    ></path></svg
                ></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              jscontroller="JGHKP"
              class="a4bIc"
              jsname="gLFyf"
              jsaction="h5M12e;input:d3sQLd;blur:jI3wzf"
            >
              <div class="pR49Ae gsfi" jsname="vdLsw"></div>
              <div
                jsname="aJyGR"
                jscontroller="DdCRH"
                class="gLFyf uKLqed gsfi"
                data-promo-open-duration="2000"
                jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md"
              >
                <g-snackbar
                  jsname="nH91he"
                  jscontroller="TrMQ4c"
                  style="display: none"
                  data-dismiss=""
                  jsshadow=""
                  jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md"
                  id="ow10"
                  __is_owner="true"
                  ><div
                    jsname="Ng57nc"
                    class="CIKhFd"
                    data-ved="0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQ4G8IFA"
                    jsowner="ow10"
                  >
                    <div class="EA3l1b">
                      <div class="Xb004" jsslot="">
                        <span class="awHmMb xy0YY ohEFXb"
                          >Press <span class="gLWQQ">/</span> to jump to the
                          search box</span
                        >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div></g-snackbar
                >
              </div>
              <input
                class="gLFyf gsfi"
                jsaction="paste:puy29d; mouseenter:MJEKMe; mouseleave:iFHZnf;"
                maxlength="2048"
                name="q"
                type="text"
                aria-autocomplete="both"
                aria-haspopup="false"
                autocapitalize="off"
                autocomplete="off"
                autocorrect="off"
                role="combobox"
                spellcheck="false"
                value="harry"
                aria-label="Search"
                data-ved="0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQ39UDCBU"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="dRYYxd">
              <div
                jscontroller="PymCCe"
                class="BKRPef M2vV3"
                jsname="RP0xob"
                aria-label="Clear"
                role="button"
                jsaction="AVsnlb;rcuQ6b:npT2md"
                data-ved="0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQ05YFCBY"
              >
                <span
                  class="ExCKkf z1asCe rzyADb"
                  jsname="itVqKe"
                  role="button"
                  tabindex="0"
                  aria-label="Clear"
                  ><svg
                    focusable="false"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"
                    ></path></svg
                ></span>
                <span class="ACRAdd"></span>
              </div>
              <div
                jscontroller="iBsgfb"
                class="hpuQDe"
                aria-label="Search by voice"
                role="button"
                tabindex="0"
                jsaction="h5M12e;rcuQ6b:npT2md"
                data-ved="0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQvs8DCBc"
              >
                <svg
                  class="HPVvwb"
                  focusable="false"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    fill="#4285f4"
                    d="m12 15c1.66 0 3-1.31 3-2.97v-7.02c0-1.66-1.34-3.01-3-3.01s-3 1.34-3 3.01v7.02c0 1.66 1.34 2.97 3 2.97z"
                  ></path>
                  <path fill="#34a853" d="m11 18.08h2v3.92h-2z"></path>
                  <path
                    fill="#fbbc05"
                    d="m7.05 16.87c-1.27-1.33-2.05-2.83-2.05-4.87h2c0 1.45 0.56 2.42 1.47 3.38v0.32l-1.15 1.18z"
                  ></path>
                  <path
                    fill="#ea4335"
                    d="m12 16.93a4.97 5.25 0 0 1 -3.54 -1.55l-1.41 1.49c1.26 1.34 3.02 2.13 4.95 2.13 3.87 0 6.99-2.92 6.99-7h-1.99c0 2.92-2.24 4.93-5 4.93z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            class="Tg7LZd"
            jsname="Tg7LZd"
            aria-label="Google Search"
            type="submit"
            data-ved="0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQ4dUDCBg"
          >
            <div class="FAuhyb">
              <span class="z1asCe MZy1Rb"
                ><svg
                  focusable="false"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"
                  ></path></svg
              ></span>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div
          jscontroller="J7ZZy"
          class="UUbT9"
          style="display: none"
          jsname="UUbT9"
          jsaction="mouseout:ItzDCd;mouseleave:MWfikb;hBEIVb:nUZ9le;YMFC3:VKssTb"
        >
          <div class="RjPuVb" jsname="RjPuVb"></div>
          <div class="aajZCb" jsname="aajZCb">
            <div class="xtSCL"></div>
            <ul class="erkvQe" jsname="erkvQe" role="listbox"></ul>
            <li class="ynRric V88cHc" id="ynRric" role="presentation"></li>
            <li data-view-type="1" class="sbct" id="YMXe" role="presentation">
              <div class="eIPGRd">
                <div class="sbic"></div>
                <div class="pcTkSc" role="option">
                  <div class="wM6W7d"><span></span></div>
                  <div class="ClJ9Yb"><span></span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="AQZ9Vd"><div class="sbai">Remove</div></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li
              class="IDVnvc"
              data-view-type="6"
              id="TN4rFf"
              role="presentation"
            >
              <div class="cRV9hb">
                <div class="aVbWac"><div class="sbic"></div></div>
                <div class="pcTkSc" role="option">
                  <div class="wM6W7d"><span></span></div>
                  <div class="ClJ9Yb"><span></span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div
            jsname="JUypV"
            jscontroller="N9swdb"
            class="JUypV"
            data-async-context="async_id:duf3-46;authority:0;card_id:;entry_point:0;feature_id:;ftoe:0;header:0;is_jobs_spam_form:0;open:0;preselect_answer_index:-1;suggestions:;suggestions_subtypes:;suggestions_types:;surface:0;title:;type:46"
          >
            <div
              jscontroller="xz7cCd"
              style="display: none"
              jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md"
            ></div>
            <div
              id="duf3-46"
              data-jiis="up"
              data-async-type="duffy3"
              data-async-context-required="type,open,feature_id,async_id,entry_point,authority,card_id,ftoe,title,header,suggestions,surface,suggestions_types,suggestions_subtypes,preselect_answer_index,is_jobs_spam_form"
              class="yp"
              data-ved="0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQ-0EIGQ"
            ></div>
            <a
              class="oBa0Fe wrSo4 aciXEb"
              href="#"
              id="sbfblt"
              data-async-trigger="duf3-46"
              role="button"
              jsaction="trigger.szjOR"
              data-ved="0ahUKEwjvw4DXwdPwAhUNqBQKHX1jCTAQtw8IGg"
              >Report inappropriate predictions</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        style="
          background: url(/images/searchbox/desktop_searchbox_sprites318_hr.webp);
        "
      ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tophf">
      <input name="rlz" value="1C5CHFA_enIR733IR733" type="hidden" /><input
        value="zdijYK-pCI3QUv3GpYAD"
        name="ei"
        type="hidden"
      /><input
        value="AINFCbYAAAAAYKPm3dz25dXXhAXsXs7W_at7vVHXOtaw"
        disabled="true"
        name="iflsig"
        type="hidden"
      />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Include example HTML of the elements (and ancestors) you are trying to target.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done. I assumed it was easier for people to just Google sth themselves and use the devtools than read some HTML here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```css
#searchform * > div {
   /*  display: none; */
   width: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

```
#top_nav > *, div[role=navigation] {
    /* font-size: 2em !important;; */
    zoom: 200% ;
}
```

[Recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css) selection is also useful.

Answer (score -1):

A little poking around in the Web Inspector gave me the search box is `.RNNXgb` and the top nav is `.GLcBOb`.

Comment: This is very likely to break, as the names suggest that  they were auto-generated. I like to use something maintainable.

Comment: It was the same class [two years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20190731235824/https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl). I don't think it'll change in the near future.