# How can i selected all nested paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

i have the following HTML

```
<div class="parentt">
        <h2>sdsd</h2>
        <p>p 1</p>
        <p>p 2</p>
        <p>p 3</p>
</div>
```

so if i want to style all paragraphs inside i will do

```
.parentt p:nth-of-type {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

but if i have nested paragraphs for example

```
<div class="parentt">
        <h2>sdsd</h2>
        <p>p 1</p>
        <p>p 2</p>
        <p>p 3</p>
       <div class="my-div-with-nested-p">
          <p>nested p 1</p>
         <div> <p>nested p 2</p></div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

then my css code does not work.How can i style the nested paragraphs - `nested p 1` and `nested p 2` automatically throught the parent like in the first case ?

Comment: Which element you want to select ?

Comment: Are you wanting to style the nested `p` as well as the normal `p` tags? You can just remove your `:nth-of-type` if this is the case and it will style all `p` tags inside of `parentt`

Comment: ```.parentt p {}``` will give you all the `p` tags in this ```div```.

Comment: did you try like this? `p { /* css codes... */ }` in this case you don't need any nested selectors, apparently you didn't search before: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css`

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Descendant selectors** to select a nested child.

```css
.parentt * p, .parentt > p{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentt">
        <h2>sdsd</h2>
        <p>p 1</p>
        <p>p 2</p>
        <p>p 3</p>
       <div class="my-div-with-nested-p">
          <p>nested p 1</p>
         <div> <p>nested p 2</p></div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Official Specification: [5.5 Descendant selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

**OR**

You can directly apply properties to all `<p>`  inside `.parentt` div.

```css
.parentt p{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parentt">
            <h2>sdsd</h2>
            <p>p 1</p>
            <p>p 2</p>
            <p>p 3</p>
           <div class="my-div-with-nested-p">
              <p>nested p 1</p>
             <div> <p>nested p 2</p></div>
           </div>
    </div>
```