# Select All Link Element On Hover CSS

Tags: css, hover

I have this on my hover [CSS](https://angora.id/style.css) ->

```
.menu-icon:hover,
.source-icon:hover,
.title h1:hover,
.title h2:hover, 
.list-title h1:hover,
.list-title h2:hover,
.single-content a:hover,
.button:hover,
.pagination .prev:hover,
.pagination .next:hover,
.copyright:hover,
.copyright a:hover {
fill: #e00;
color: #e00;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify about selecting all link element on hover CSS?

Because I tried `*a:hover` or `* + a:hover` but it doesn't work?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We will need, at a minimum, the relevant HTML

Comment: https://angora.id/blog/

Comment: That's not what I asked. You need to post your [mcve] here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything before the :hover if you want to apply the effect to all elements when hovered over.  Sadly, this will make the effect apply to everything and is probably what you don't want.  I would create a new class in css with the hover attributes and then add the class to all the buttons and elements in your HTML

```
  .hover:hover {
    fill: #e00;
    color: #e00;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910083/17751007).

With `*:hover` you are selecting the root element itself. As you want to select every single element, what you are looking for is to select all HTML body's children, for example.

```css
body *:hover {
  fill: #e00;
  color: #e00;
}
```

Exactly what you are looking for, for linked elements would be:

```css
body a *:hover {
  fill: #e00;
  color: #e00;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code. Yes something like this but only for all linked elements.

Comment: Linked elements should only be the ones that have an <a> around them. So you can use that in the rule. For example, body a *:hover, all the childs of a link...

Comment: I edited the question to include this final answer.